# Confused on how Method of Manufactured solutions works?

Tags: finite-element, convergence, verification

I am new to computational science and I am trying to wrap my head around how MMS works. I am solving the time independent Helmholtz equation as a simple test of the technique

so my starting equation is following with homogeneous boundary conditions on a line segment

$\Delta u +k^2u = F $

So I am supposed to take something that is sufficiently differentiable. So, following other people I pick the following for my 1D case

$ \bar{u} = \sin(\pi x)$

My new source term created from MMS would be

$G(x) = -\pi^2\sin(\pi x) + k^{2}\sin(\pi x) - F $

Now here is where I am stuck. I picked a u and now I have a new F. Somehow I am supposed to be able to verify my rate of convergence of my actual problem with this fictitious one. Are the points the same?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, the non-homogeneous time-independent Helmholtz equation is: $$\nabla^{2} u + k^{2} u = F$$ Then if I assume your fabricated solution of $u = \sin(\pi x)$, I would have this for $F$ as: $$F = (k^{2} - \pi^{2}) \sin(\pi x)$$ Basically, if you have this equation: $$\frac{d^{2} u}{d x^{2}} + k^{2} u = (k^{2} - \pi^{2}) \sin(\pi x)$$ The analytical solution would be: $u = \sin(\pi x)$.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer I had F as some arbitrary forcing function so how does that change your comment. Also I am not sure how this relates to my original problem. How does this new equation help me check convergence?

Comment: In your code to solve this Helmholtz equation, you put the right-hand side as $F = (k^{2}-\pi^{2})\sin(\pi x)$ then compare your numerical result with the analytical solution of $u = \sin(\pi x)$ to find the rate of convergence of your method with respect to mesh size.

Comment: The point is that you cannot *independently* choose whatever solution and right hand side you have in the equation. You can only choose one, and then the other is determined. So if you pick a $\bar u$, then it follows from the equation what $F$ needs to be.